# Slow Shutter Speed on Aperture Mode

Tags: nikon, shutter, nikon-d90

I'm a new photographer. I have a Nikon D90 taken from my votech that I had been trying out and messing with all night last night. Then today when I go to take some photos, I decide to do a reset using the exposure and AF buttons. After I do that, the camera takes a good second after the shutter closes to open back up, resulting in terrible blurry photos. When I use AUTO it turns out fine but when I use any other mode (aperture mode is my favorite), it is terribly slow. My exposure is set at 0, the white balance is auto, the auto focus is AF-C, I'm on single shot mode, the whole shabang. It was taking photos fine before I reset it. What do I need to do to get it back to normal speed? Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: What are the ISO and aperture set to?

Comment: @xiota thank you for responding so fast! I actually figured it out. It was the ISO combined with the super low light setting I was trying to shoot in. Thank you though!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the relationship between ISO, aperture, and shutter speed?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/72388/what-is-the-relationship-between-iso-aperture-and-shutter-speed)

Comment: Essentially the same question using ISO instead of shutter time as the variable: [Why is my camera metering indoor scenes as darker than I expect, forcing me to use a high ISO?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/48668/15871)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is my camera metering indoor scenes as darker than I expect, forcing me to use a high ISO?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/48668/why-is-my-camera-metering-indoor-scenes-as-darker-than-i-expect-forcing-me-to-u)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You said "all night", which sounds like it was too dark for your settings. Ways to get a faster shutter speed are:

1. Go into a more bright area with enough light, where automation can do better.  Photography is tough without enough light.  One way to provide more light is to use flash.
2. Open the aperture and/or increase the ISO so that a faster shutter can work.  If you are now seeing a shutter speed about 1 second, then it sounds like you need at least 5 or 6 stops more, to still be slow, but perhaps adequate.
3. You can use S or M mode to directly set a faster shutter speed. Then automation will increase Auto ISO, and/or A mode will open the aperture more, if it still has room to go so can it open more.

Frankly, what you seriously need to know something about is camera exposure.  In Google searches, this is often called [the exposure triangle](https://www.google.com/search?&q=exposure+triangle) (see the related question here, [What is the "exposure triangle"?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/6598/what-is-the-exposure-triangle)) which is not a great name (there is no triangle, there are just the three factors), but it is an extremely important idea to know anything at all about using the camera. It is about how shutter speed, aperture, and ISO combinations all work together to provide exposure, but specifically, the settings you need for a situation, like stopping motion or increasing depth of field.  You can find a lot about that topic on Google to become informed about exposure.  It is about the first thing a photographer has to learn.

Comment: Why not link to Photo-SE's [`exposure`](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/exposure?tab=Votes) questions, at least first, before driving traffic off-site to Google searches?